# OOP in memory level

Tags: oop, memory

I'm looking for some articles or tutorials about realization of Object Oriented paradigms in memory level. I want to understand how objects are located in memory, how inheritance, encapsulation and polymorphism are realized in low level.
  Can someone provide me useful online resource with good examples?

Comment: The answer varies between languages. Pick a language and ask a specific question.

Comment: I thought that basic principles are the same. I want to know how it is implemented in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read an electronic book [Object Oriented Memory Management 
(Java and C++)](http://task3.cc/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/object-oriented-memory-management-java-c++.pdf). It will give you good overiview of memory management in OOP.